# why is delete function not working in hive shell?

Tags: hive, hiveql

```sql
hive> delete from daily_case where num_casedaily=0;

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations.
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: not using any distribution on the table. should i use distribute by clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hive` doesn't support `ACID` transactions in a conventional way. You will need some pre-requisites and undestand limitations of `ACID` Transactions in `Hive`.

You can review this article:

[using-hive-acid-transactions-to-insert-update-and-delete-data](https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/using-hive-acid-transactions-to-insert-update-and-delete-data/.html#operational-tools-for-acid)

for more information on `Hive` Transactions.

**Pre -Requisites**
Hive Transactions Manager should be set to `DbTxnManager` `SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;`

We need to enable concurrency `SET hive.support.concurrency=true;`

Once we set the above properties, we should be able to insert data into any table.
For updates and deletes, table should be bucketed and file format need to be `ORC` or any `ACID Compliant Format`.
We also need to set table property transactions to true `TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');`

#### REVIEW PROPERTIES

```sh
$ cd /etc/hive/conf

$ grep -i txn hive-site.xml

$ hive -e "SET;" | grep -i txn

$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/training_retail
```

As an example to create a transactional table in `HIVE`

```sql
SET hive.txn.manager;
hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DummyTxnManager;

SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;

SET hive.support.concurrency=true;

SET hive.enforce.bucketing;
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode;
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=strict

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

SET hive.compactor.initiator.on;
SET hive.compactor.initiator.on=true;
-- A positive number
SET hive.compactor.worker.threads;
SET hive.compactor.worker.threads=1;

CREATE TABLE orders_transactional (
  order_id INT,
  order_date STRING,
  order_customer_id INT,
  order_status STRING
) CLUSTERED BY (order_id) INTO 8 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC
TBLPROPERTIES("transactional"="true");

INSERT INTO orders_transactional VALUES
(1, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0', 1000, 'COMPLETE');

INSERT INTO orders_transactional VALUES
(2, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0', 2001, 'CLOSED'),
(3, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0', 1500, 'PENDING'),
(4, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0', 2041, 'PENDING'),
(5, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0', 2031, 'COMPLETE');

UPDATE orders_transactional
  SET order_status = 'COMPLETE'
WHERE order_status = 'PENDING';

DELETE FROM orders_transactional
WHERE order_status <> 'COMPLETE';

SELECT *
FROM orders_transactional;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Chema explained ACID Transactions of HIVE. You can change the table property to allow transaction.

OR

You can do the following. With this you don't have to change table properties.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO daily_case
SELECT * FROM daily_case WHERE num_casedaily <> 0;
```