# How can I update the values of table using spark sql or hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have tried working with the update statement but I think spark SQL doesn't allow it.

Comment: You could follow this link to understand ACID transactions in HIVE:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61329206/why-is-delete-function-not-working-in-hive-shell/61339632#61339632  , I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where and how your data is stored. 
If your data is stored in HDFS or other kind of object stores(like S3) your data is immutable.

A single option is in case you have your Hive table defined as transactional. In this case the table has to be clustered and stored as ORC.

In other cases unfortunately you can't update.
More information about hive transactions you can find here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions